# What is the difference between layout-sw801dp and layout-v21?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-resources

When I have a device with 900dp and when I'm running on api level 21+ when a layout file is present under all these folders,

```
res/layout/
res/layout-sw801dp/
res/layout-v21/
```

Which one would get picked up and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the *Android App Resources Overview* specifically [providing alternate resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources). Table 2 describes the available resource qualifiers. It is stated there that

> Table 2 lists the valid configuration qualifiers, in order of precedence...

So, looking at that list, you have resources defined in the following directories:

res/layout/: defaults
res/layout-sw801dp/ : smallest width
res/layout-v21/ : version 21 and above

The priority order is as ffollows and the search for the resource will stop at the first match.

res/layout-sw801dp/
res/layout-v21/
res/layout/

Since your screen has a width of 900dp, the search for the resource would stop at *res/layout-sw801dp* since 900dp >= 801dp. If the screen width were 700dp (<801dp) and the API level 21+, the search would stop at *res/layout-v21/*. If the version were, say API 18 and the screen width 700dp then *res/layout/* would be used.